# Linux command to trim log file

Tags: text-processing

1) I have a log file named version.txt and need to filter out all words with key word "took ? ms".. The number before ms ("took ?? ms") varies for each log entry.

Output should be as below:

```
took 4 ms
took 3 ms
took 4 ms
took 5 ms
```

2) Also it is possible to list down took > 100. i.e.. it should list down values which are more than 100.
Output should be like;

```
took 100 ms
took 110 ms
took 450 ms
```

## **Log file:**

```
2020-03-11 06:19:29.857  INFO 29371 --- [  async-task-32] c.l.s.mapstore.InventoryPictureMapStore  : InventoryPictureMapStore.store() called **took 4 ms** key: I,748518,00000,00000,595 Value: InventoryPicture [, sourcingEnabled=false, itemType=1, onHand_1=100, buffer_22=-1] writeToCassandra: true

2020-03-11 06:19:29.857  INFO 29371 --- [  async-task-10] c.l.s.mapstore.InventoryPictureMapStore  : InventoryPictureMapStore.store() called **took 3 ms** key: I,26221,00000,00000,595 Value: InventoryPicture [, sourcingEnabled=false, itemType=1, onHand_1=-29, damaged_3=-1] writeToCassandra: true

2020-03-11 06:19:29.857  INFO 29371 --- [  async-task-13] c.l.s.mapstore.InventoryPictureMapStore  : InventoryPictureMapStore.store() called **took 4 ms** key: I,960808,00000,00000,595 Value: InventoryPicture [, sourcingEnabled=false, itemType=1, onHand_1=14] writeToCassandra: true

2020-03-11 06:19:29.857  INFO 29371 --- [  async-task-30] c.l.s.mapstore.InventoryPictureMapStore  : InventoryPictureMapStore.store() called **took 5 ms** key: I,771963,00000,00000,595 Value: InventoryPicture [, sourcingEnabled=false, itemType=1, onHand_1=64, buffer_22=-1] writeToCassandra: true


2020-03-11 06:19:29.857  INFO 29371 --- [  async-task-30] c.l.s.mapstore.InventoryPictureMapStore  : InventoryPictureMapStore.store() called **took 100 ms** key: I,771963,00000,00000,595 Value: InventoryPicture [, sourcingEnabled=false, itemType=1, onHand_1=64, buffer_22=-1] writeToCassandra: true

2020-03-11 06:19:29.857  INFO 29371 --- [  async-task-30] c.l.s.mapstore.InventoryPictureMapStore  : InventoryPictureMapStore.store() called **took 110 ms** key: I,771963,00000,00000,595 Value: InventoryPicture [, sourcingEnabled=false, itemType=1, onHand_1=64, buffer_22=-1] writeToCassandra: true

2020-03-11 06:19:29.857  INFO 29371 --- [  async-task-30] c.l.s.mapstore.InventoryPictureMapStore  : InventoryPictureMapStore.store() called **took 400 ms** key: I,771963,00000,00000,595 Value: InventoryPicture [, sourcingEnabled=false, itemType=1, onHand_1=64, buffer_22=-1] writeToCassandra: true
```

Comment: Please use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format your log file as code so we can see _exactly_ what it is like. And, as we asked in your previous question, please show us the output you expect from this example. Are you just looking for `grep -oP 'took \d+ ms' logfile`?

Comment: Seems like an [answer from your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/572161/117549) could be adapted rather easily...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `awk` using this way:

```
awk -F '**' '{print $2}' input_file
```

TO add time and date you can use something like:

```
awk -F '**' '{split($1,a," ");print a[1]" " a[2]" " $2}' input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

This you can try:

```
grep -oP "took [[:digit:]]{3,} ms" file
```

Output:

```
took 100 ms
took 110 ms
took 400 ms
```

---

> Thanks. is it possible to list down the date/time as well? something like this as output :
>
> 2020-03-11 06:19:29.857 took 100 ms
>
> 2020-03-11 06:19:29.857 took 110 ms

Assuming all the records have the same format, it's easier with `cut`, `sed` and `grep`:

```
cut -d' ' -f1,2,15-17 file | sed 's/*//g' | grep -P "took [[:digit:]]{3,} ms"

2020-03-11 06:19:29.857 took 100 ms
2020-03-11 06:19:29.857 took 110 ms
2020-03-11 06:19:29.857 took 400 ms
```

Comment: Thanks. is it possible to list down the date/time as well? something like this as output : 2020-03-11 06:19:29.857  took 100 ms
2020-03-11 06:19:29.857 took 110 ms